# Open GL : Changing Brightness and Contrast of the Image

Tags: iphone, opengl-es

I have one module to implement in which I have to change the Brightness and Contrast of the Image for IPhone.

After ref some samples like GLImageProcessing , seems need to go with Open GL (In this sample, we can able to do one activity at a time either brightness or contrast), As I am new to this Open GL and not able to work out with this.

Kindly provide me some threads or ref regarding same ,it will be helpful to move in right direction.

thanks,
Sagar

Comment: By "assignment" do you mean "homework"?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try google: glPixelTransferf and GL_RED_SCALE
Here's some ref: http://pyopengl.sourceforge.net/documentation/manual/glPixelTransfer.3G.html